# Perl Tk window autoclosing on browsing directory

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I am developing a desktop client using Perl's [Tk](http://search.cpan.org/~srezic/Tk-804.034/Tk.pod) module. I have a button which opens the directory for the particular task. But the problem I am facing is it closes my Perl interface which I dont want to.

Below is the sub which implements the logic for directory open:

```
sub open_directory {
  my $directory = shift;
  print "comes here atleast for $directory";
  if ($^O eq 'MSWin32') {
    exec "start $directory";
  }
  else {
    die "cannot open folder on your system: $^O";
  }
}
```

I am calling this sub via:

```
sub second_window{

    my $row = 0;
    $mw2 = new MainWindow; 

    #Loop for listing taskname,path and browse button for all tasks of a region
    for my $i(1..$#tasks_region_wise){
        $row = $row+1;
        $frame_table-> Label(-text=>$sno+$i,-font=>"calibri")->grid(-row=>$row,-column=>0,-sticky=>'w');
        $frame_table-> Label(-text=>$tasks_region_wise[$i][2],-font=>"calibri")->grid(-row=>$row,-column=>1,-sticky=>'w');
        $frame_table-> Label(-text=>$tasks_region_wise[$i][3],-font=>"calibri")->grid(-row=>$row,-column=>2,-sticky=>'w');


#Calling that sub in the below line:

        $frame_table->Button(-text => 'Browse',-relief =>'raised',-font=>"calibri",-command => [\&open_directory, $tasks_region_wise[$i][3]],-activebackground=>'green',)->grid(-row=>$row,-column=>3);
        $frame_table->Button(-text => 'Execute',-relief =>'raised',-font=>"calibri",-command => [\&open_directory, $tasks_region_wise[$i][4]],-activebackground=>'green',)->grid(-row=>$row,-column=>4);
        $frame_table->Button(-text => 'Detail',-relief =>'raised',-font=>"calibri",-command => [\&popupBox, $tasks_region_wise[$i][2],$tasks_region_wise[$i][5]],-activebackground=>'green',)->grid(-row=>$row,-column=>5);

    }
    $frame_table->Label()->grid(-row=>++$row);
    $frame_table->Button(-text => 'Back',-relief =>'raised',-font=>"calibri",-command => \&back,-activebackground=>'green',)->grid(-row=>++$row,-columnspan=>4);

    MainLoop;
}
```

It opens the File explorer window properly but closes the Perl interface.

Comment: I think the problem is the `exec` call which replace your current running executable with a new one.

Comment: Thanks for that point @ulix, I have got the workaround for it by using system function instead of the exec call.

Answer (score 2):

Posting for future reference to anyone facing this issue. I just got the proper problem as commented by a fellow Stackoverflow user @ulix.

**Problem:** The issue here was that the exec call was causing this current script execution to stop and executed the start directory command.

**Solution:** Convert the exec call to system call which does not fires the exec and is handled by Perl instead.

PFB the updated code of the sub:

```
sub open_directory {
  my $directory = shift;
  print "comes here atleast for $directory";
  if ($^O eq 'MSWin32') {
    system("start $directory");
  }
  else {
    die "cannot open folder on your system: $^O";
  }
}
```